# Using an http response code/message to dictate a redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I'm calling an API endpoint below and catching any errors coming back directly from it, decoding and showing those as errors:

```
try {
        $authService = new AuthService();
        $login = $authService->loginGetToken($email, $password);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        $message = $response->message;

        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($message);
    }
```

My issue: If a password is expired, I get back a 400 error with the message "Password is Expired"

Is there a way in my catch block to check if it's that code and message, and if so, redirect them to view `auth.reset` to reset their password?

Comment: Yes of course.  You are already doing a redirect, so add some code that checks for the specific error# and add an if-then-else block that redirects to the url you want to.

Comment: Part of my issue: The user can get multiple kinds of 400 errors, but only the one with this message needs to direct to auth.reset. How can I check the content of the message though?

Comment: You can call `$e->getMessage()` ... http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php ... there is also a `$e-getCode()` to get the code since you asked about both.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: The message is coming back from a guzzle client. If I dump $message on the page, it just says "Password is expired"

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply check that message?

Comment: If you're using Guzzle client then check out [exception handling](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#exception). Chances are you need to specifically `RequestException`. You can check the response that generated the exception with `getResponse` and that will contain the status code. You can use that in a block of if statements to determine the place to redirect to. This is going to be preferable to parsing exception messages

Comment: Not that I knew of, but I guess I wanted to see if there was a more appropriate way. I would check code but they can have multiple reasons for the same code

Comment: If you want to be extra careful then `if $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == 400 && $message == '...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `$e->getMessage()` ... http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php ... there is also a `$e->getCode()` to get the code since you asked about both.

So something like:

```
if($e->getMessage() == 'Password is Expired') {
    return redirect('auth/reset'); // or whatever your route is
}
```

Or using your code:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (\Exception $) {
    $response = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
    $message = $response->message;
    if($message == 'Password is Expired') {
        return redirect('auth/reset'); // or whatever your route is
    }
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($message);
}
```

You may also find that you are getting a specific type of Exception that you could catch:

```
catch (PasswordExpiredException $e) {
    ... // password is expired
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ... // something else happened
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm already getting the message though. My code for that is above, so it properly dumps the response. I just don't know the best way to say ```if response == 'Password is Expired' then redirect```

Comment: in my code, $message dumps what I need to see. I just need to check it as a condition for redirect

Comment: OK, it looks like you just need to check the message and then redirect if needed. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I believe that's working thanks. Is there a way to check if it's similar, like a mysql LIKE operator?

Comment: You could use Laravel's `Str::contains()` to check if it contains 'Password' or something. You might also check my edited answer since you might be getting a specific type of exception.

Comment: You should be able to check the class by dumping `get_class($e)` to see what it is.